# Construct random variable $X$ such that $P(X\in A\mid T=t) = \mu_t(A)$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Fix a family of distributions $(\mu_t)_{t\in \mathbb{R}}$ on a Polish space $S$. I know, for instance, I can always construct a probability space on which for each $t \in \mathbb{R}$, there is a random variable $X_t$ with distribution $\mu_t$, and $(X_t)_t$ is an independent family.

Is it possible to "wrap them all up" in some way?
Suppose $T$ is a random variable on $\mathbb{R}$.
Then I want a random variable $X$ (taking values in $S$) such that $P(X \in A\mid T=t) = \mu_t(A)$ (equivalently $P(X\in A\mid T) = \mu_T(A))$.

My first instinct says to try $X := X_t$ on the event $\{T=t\}$, but my second instinct says the fact that there are uncountably many $t$ is going to make $X$ not measurable.

Comment: I guess $G$ should be $S$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\nu$ be a given probability distribution on $(\Bbb R,\mathcal B)$, where $\mathcal B$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algerba on $\Bbb R$. If $t\mapsto \mu_t(A)$ is Borel measurable for each $A\in\mathcal S$ (the Borel subsets of $S$) then you can define a probability measure $\Bbb P$ on $(S\times,\Bbb R,\mathcal S\otimes\mathcal B)$ by setting
$$
\Bbb P(B):=\int_{\Bbb R}\mu_t(B^t)\,d\nu(t),\qquad B\in S\otimes\mathcal B,
$$
where $B^t:=\{s\in S: (s,t)\in B\}$. The random variables $X:S\times\Bbb R\to S$ defined by $X(s,t)=s$ and $T:S\times\Bbb B\to\Bbb R$ defined by $T(s,t)=t$ then have the property you seek.

Comment: +1 For pointing this out, but in my case I don't know if I have Borel measurability.

Comment: Not much you can do then unless the distribution of $T$ is supported on a countable set.